# Own Eq instance for binary trees

Tags: haskell

I am trying to create my own `Eq` instance for binary trees:

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) 
instance Eq a => Eq (Tree a) where
    (Empty == Empty) = True
    (Empty == _)     = False
    (_ == Empty)     = False
    (Node x xl xr) == (Node y yl yr) = (x == y) && xl == yl && xr == yr
```

I get the following error message:

```
Parse error in pattern: Empty == Empty
```

Could you tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: remove parentheses, `( x == y )` should be just `x == y`

Comment: Thanks, is it ok generally way ?

Comment: Note: you *must* remove the parentheses around the outermost patterns, but you *should* remove all the parentheses in the code except the ones around the type `Tree a`. None of them are necessary.

Comment: Yes, it works. From what I know I should know when parentheses are needed?

Comment: in pattern matches (the left hand side of definitions), parenthesis are used to group the structure of _individual_ arguments. Since `==` is a function with two arguments, then you shouldn't have parens that group everything including that function name, otherwise the compiler gets confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not use parentheses while defining an operator or a function. Keep in mind that

```
a ???? b
```

is just syntactical sugar for

```
(????) a b
```

Therefore, your patterns should be like this:

```
Empty == Empty = True
Empty == _     = False
_ == Empty     = False
Node x xl xr == Node y yl yr = ...
```